# Покраска Excel при экспорте

Tags: c#, excel

нужно покрасить определенные столбцы в другой цвет, но проблема в том, что он красит не только столбцы, но и все ячейки до конца файла, как это исправить?

```
var start = workSheet.Dimension.Start;
            var end = workSheet.Dimension.End;
            for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
            {

                if (workSheet.Cells[1, col].Text == "STATUS51")
                {
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("lightgreen"));
                }
                if (workSheet.Cells[1, col].Text == "LENGTH52")
                {
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("lightgreen"));
                }

                if (workSheet.Cells[1, col].Text == "MTC")
                {
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("lightgreen"));

                }

            }
```

Comment: *он красит не только столбцы, но и все ячейки до конца файла* Столбец включает ВСЕ ячейки столбца от первой строки и до последней. *как это исправить?* Красить надо только нужный Range.

Comment: не подскажите, как это реализовать? покрасить весь столбец, но только пока данные идут

Comment: `Column(col)` - столбец, `Cells[1, col]` - ячейка в первой строке столбца, Вам осталось найти, как определять `Range` в столбце

Comment: Не подскажите, куда Range вставить?

Comment: Что-то типа `Range(workSheet.Cells[1, col].Address & ":" & workSheet.Cells[1, col].End(xlDown).Address)`

Comment: Что -то такое? UsedRange2(workSheet.Cells[1, col].Address & ":" & workSheet.Cells[1, col].End(xlDown).Address).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    UsedRange2(workSheet.Cells[1, col].Address & ":" & workSheet.Cells[1, col].End(xlDown).Address).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Green); Пишет, что оператор & не возможно применить к методу String и на End(xlDown) ругается

Comment: Совершенно не знаю C#... Но 5 минут поиска (взято на `qaru.site/questions/88699/write-array-to-excel-range`): `Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)wsh.Cells[topRow, 1]; === 
        Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)wsh.Cells[topRow + dt.Rows.Count - 1, dt.Columns.Count]; ===
        Excel.Range range = wsh.get_Range(c1, c2); ===` три "равно" - для отметки разделения строк (убрать из кода)

Comment: Ругается на get_Range и topRow. И не особо понимаю куда его вставлять

Comment: Я показал только направление (надеюсь, правильное)  Немного смекалки... У Вас этих переменных нет. посмотрите код по ссылке, примените к своему.  Первая строка фрагмента кода определяет первую ячейку, вторая - последнюю. В третьей указываем диапазон - от первой до последней - `Range(c1, c2)`.

Comment: Так проблема в том, что я не знаю, какая именно у меня будет последняя

Comment: Нужно не только ждать ответа. Поиск-то не отменили... (взято на `qaru.site/questions/12343519/count-used-cells-in-row-using-excel-interop`) `int endRow = startRow + worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;` или так `int endRow = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count +worksheet.UsedRange.Row - 1`