# Как в EPPLUS получить номер последней заполненой ячейки в столбце

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Хочу подкрасить светло зеленым цветом столбцы в первой строке которых есть определенное значение.

Если делаю вот так:

```
     var start = workSheet.Dimension.Start;
     var end = workSheet.Dimension.End;
     for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
        {

            if (workSheet.Cells[1, col].Text == "Нужное значение")
            {
                workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                workSheet.Column(col).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("lightgreen"));
            }
    }
```

То получается закрашенный полностью столбец, при этом закрашен он полностью (т.е. 65к строк, когда в документе строк всего ~10).

Попытался обойти проблему путем введения метода:

```
 private void SetColumnLightGreen(int ColumnNumber)
 {
          var end =workSheet.Cells.Where(c => c.Start.Column == col && !c.Value.ToString().Equals("")).Last();
          for(int i=0;i<end;i++)
          {
              workSheet.Cells[i, ColumnNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
              workSheet.Cells[i, ColumnNumber].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("lightgreen"));
          }                                 
  }
```

Компилятор говорит что end -ExelRangeBase, как из него получить номер строки, которая мне нужна?

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013340/Покраска-excel-при-экспорте, там обсуждался поиск границ пользовательского диапазона. Возможно, поможет

Comment: @vikttur там немного другая библиотека взята, там итероп - который тербует обязательной установки ексель, здесь задача, состоит в том что-бы используя встраиваемую библиотечку (без установки ексель), делать такое, но спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

собственно все просто:

```
private void SetColumnLightGreen(int ColumnNumber)
    {
        ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
        var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Products");
        var end = workSheet.Cells.Where(c => c.Start.Column == ColumnNumber && !c.Value.ToString().Equals("")).Last().End.Row;
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[i, ColumnNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            workSheet.Cells[i, ColumnNumber].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("lightgreen"));
        }
    }
```

оказалось есть нужное, просто я ступил...